# Ketama hash explanation

Tags: hashing

(I originally posted this on stackoverflow but thought it would be a better fit here)

I'm trying to understand the Ketama hash code used in consistent hashing.

[link](https://github.com/RJ/ketama/blob/master/java_ketama/SockIOPool.java#L517-L532) and snippet below:

```
public static Long md5HashingAlg(String key) {
    MessageDigest md5 = null;
    try {
        md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error("++++ no md5 algorythm found");
        throw new IllegalStateException("++++ no md5 algorythm found");
    }
    md5.reset();
    md5.update(key.getBytes());
    byte[] bKey = md5.digest();
    long res = ((long) (bKey[3] & 0xFF) << 24)
        | ((long) (bKey[2] & 0xFF) << 16)
        | ((long) (bKey[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (long) (bKey[0] & 0xFF);

    return res;
}
```

I think I understand what the code is doing, but I don't get why they're doing it. Particularly, I'm wondering why:

1. the code discards the least significant 8 bytes of the 16-byte MD5 and uses only the first four (bKey[0] through bKey[3]).
2. the code "flips" the significant bytes meaning that, of the 4 bytes from 1., the least significant now become the most significant (at least that's what I understand happens from the `& 0xff`s and left shifts).

I also came across another piece of code that uses the same logic as above, but in addition performs an `& 0xffffffffL` on the result to "truncate to 32-bits".

[link](https://github.com/dustin/java-memcached-client/blob/c232307ad8e0c7ccc926e495dd7d5aad2d713318/src/main/java/net/spy/memcached/DefaultHashAlgorithm.java#L138-L148) and snippet:

```
case KETAMA_HASH:
    byte[] bKey = computeMd5(k);
    rv = ((long) (bKey[3] & 0xFF) << 24)
        | ((long) (bKey[2] & 0xFF) << 16)
        | ((long) (bKey[1] & 0xFF) << 8)
        | (bKey[0] & 0xFF);
    break;
    default:
    assert false;
}

return rv & 0xffffffffL; /* Truncate to 32-bits */
```

Could someone help me understand the rationale behind picking these particular bytes and re-arranging them in this particular fashion?

Comment: Reading code is ... almost impossible. Is [the article by the creator of ketama-hash](https://www.metabrew.com/article/libketama-consistent-hashing-algo-memcached-clients) enough? If not, then the only way is probably to contact him at [his github](https://github.com/RJ/ketama) or [twitter](https://twitter.com/metabrew).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a way to generate 32-bit hash for the string. 
Assuming that MD5 is a good [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), it doesn't matter which bits you take from the hash and in which order you arrange them (as long as they are different bits). The behavior of the bits should be equally unpredictable.

There's no explanation, why exactly 32 bits are required, though my guess is that it enables the use of simple integer types in the code.